# Is it possible to do that in Scala (without mutating the internal state of a class)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say, there is a class called `RemoteIdGetter`. It returns a key from a server. But it only makes a request to the server if the key is not "fresh" enough, meaning the last time it's been requested, is more or equal to 5 minutes (300 seconds). Otherwise, it returns the local "cached" value of the key.

I need to do that **without** (**no** `var`) mutating the internal state of  `RemoteIdGetter` or with a **pure functional approach**.

It might look like this:

```
class RemoteIdGetter {
  def key = {
    if (!needToAskServer) // return the local "cached" value of the key
    else makeRequest

  }

  def makeRequest = // make a request to a remote server to get the key
  def time = // current date-time
  def lastUpdatedTime = // the last date-time a key has been updated 
                        // (requested from the server)
  def needToAskServer = time - lastUpdatedTime >= 300
}
```

I wonder, is it possible? Why do I need it? I'm just curious if it's possible.

Comment: You'll find this video on the State Monad in Scala very helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure function should return same result every time you call it with the same parameter, so if you want to do this with no mutable state at all you have to generate new `RemoteIdGetter` every time you get key like this:

```
case class RemoteIdGetter(cachedKey: Option[KeyType] = None, lastUpdatedTime: Option[DateTime] = None) {
  def getKey(time: DateTime) = {
    val (key, t) = (for {
      k <- cachedKey
      lt <- lastUpdatedTime
      if (time - lt < cachePeriod)
    } yield k -> lt).getOrElse(makeRequest -> time)
    key -> RemoteIdGetter(Some(key), Some(t))
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val (key, newGetted) = oldGetter.getKey(currentDateTime)
```

You have to use latest generated `RemoteIdGetter` every time.

Alternatively you could hide mutable state. For instance you could use actor:

```
import akka.actor.ActorDSL._
val a = actor(new Act {
  become {
    case GetKey => replyAndBecome(sender)
  }

  def replyAndBecome(sender: ActorRef): {
    val key = makeRequest
    sender ! key
    become getState(key, time)
  }

  def getState(key: KeyType, lastUpdatedTime: DateTime): Receive = {
    case GetKey =>
      if (time - lastUpdatedTime < cachePeriod)
        sender ! key
      else 
        replyAndBecome(sender)
  }
})
```

There is no *visible* mutable state (like `var`, or mutable collection), but there is a hidden mutable state - actors behavior.

Comment: what's KeyType? Where do I import it from?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: `KeyType` is the type of your key, type of `makeRequest` result.

Comment: and what about DateTime, where do I import it from? I only know about Time class, but it's not possible to use it exactly this way -- value - is not a member of java.util.Date.

Comment: I don't know what is the type of your `time` and `lastUpdatedTime`. I prefer [`Joda Time`](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time), but you could use any type you like.

Comment: since `def getKey(time: DateTime)` always receive the parameter of the current date-time, it would be better just to remove it and create a method `currentDateTime` in a class `RemoteIdGetter`, isn't it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: not exactly. This makes `getKey` method not pure. Pure method have to return exactly same result with the same parameters.

Comment: I was wondering if you could show me an example of how to use it, for instance, if what cases would the class `RemoteIdGetter` be created with parameters and when without them? I can't figure out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31445/discussion-between-senia-and-marius-kavansky)

Comment: Sorry everyone: chat was in Russian. Resume, for ones who care: it's possible, but useless. For pure function style with no mutable state at all - Haskell and I/O monad. In scala - localized state in actor.

Comment: Actually I'd say a *State* Monad, not IO... for both Haskell and Scala

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to make the `RemoteIdGetter` return a pair consisting of 1. the requested key, and 2. a new instance of itself with the requested key cached. Further lookups are done against the new instance of the `RemoteIdGetter`. Automatic threading of the instances can be done with monads.

There's no particular reason you need it in Scala, since you could achieve the same thing by mutating a cache map in your class.

Something that's a little interesting is that you could just write a normal `RemoteIdGetter` function that fetches the key from online, and then write a generic caching function that wraps around *any* costly computation. This is very similar to the concept of memoization, only you keep some metadata about when you want to discard the cached result. There is no real reason the `RemoteIdGetter` should do the caching itself, when it can be offloaded to some other generic function that specialises in that.

---

#### General cacher

So, say you have a function which does something expensive. In this case, I'm just going to make it receive user input for simplicity's sake.

```py
def get_id():
    try:
        return int(input("Enter an id: "))
    except ValueError:
        return get_id()
```

This asks the user for an integer. If the user fails to enter one, it simply asks again. We don't want to bother the user with an integer all the time, so we want to cache the value the user entered for further uses. We *could* cache things in the `get_id` function, but that isn't an ideal situation, since we want [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

So what we do is we create a generic Cacher object, which can cache any value. We want to be able to do something like this:

```py
cached_id = Cacher(get_id)
cached_id.get()
```

and then get either a cached ID or ask the user for the number, depending on whether or not the number is cached/recently updated.

The `Cacher` object needs to hold data and an expiration time for the data. In this ID case, that translates to two fields in the cacher. You would probably want a map/dict here in a real-world caching object, but I'm trying to keep it simple.

```py
class Cacher:
    value = None
    expires = 0
```

You initialise the caching object with a function to call if the value isn't cached, so that's just

```py
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.external = function
```

and then the interesting bit is the `get()` method, which, in its simplest form, looks like

```py
    # Get a value and in case it is retrieved, make it good for 30 seconds
    def get(self, ttl=30):
        if not self.value or datetime.now() > self.expires:
            # Get a new value from the external source
            self.value = self.external()
            # and update the new expiration time to ttl seconds from now
            self.expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=ttl)

        return self.value
```

Then when you call `cached_id.get()` for the first time you will have to enter an integer, but any consecutive calls within 30 seconds will just retrieve the last entered integer.

This mutable Python object can of course be implemented as an actor in Scala, I just wanted to show the principle.

Comment: Would you mind giving the a rough code of the first (no mutating) and the second (no caching) approaches? Especially the first one.

Comment: **There's no particular reason you need it in Scala,** -- why? mutating a cache value would cause some problems or, at least, an extra effort, for example, if I'll will work with multi-threading.

Comment: @MariusKavansky The real gain of having it immutable in a multi-threaded situation is that you don't run the risk of half-written caches, since you only synchronise the cache manually when it is between writes. I would imagine that making atomic changes to the cache shouldn't be too difficult in Scala, though. (I would be happy to provide both the snippets you ask for, but I'm in a hurry right now. I'll be back in a couple of days.)

Comment: @MariusKavansky I edited my post now with some pseudo code for the second question. I believe your first questions was answered well enough by senia.