# Akka Type mismatch

Tags: scala, akka, type-mismatch

I am beginner in akka and I am stuck in this compilation problem :

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Outer(operation, someInt, someBool) =>
      makeOperation(operation, someInt, someBool) 
  }    

  private def makeOperation(operation: Operation, someInt: Int, someBool: Boolean): Receive = {
    operation match {
      case MainOp(otherInt) =>
        if (someBool) {
          if (otherInt < someInt) {
            root ! makeMessage(...)
          } else if (otherInt > someInt) {
            root ! makeMessage(...) // <-  compilation error here
          } else {
            root ! makeMessage(...) // <-  compilation error here
          }
        } else {
          if (otherInt > someInt) {
            root ! makeMessage(...) // <-  compilation error here
          } else if (otherInt < someInt) {
            root ! makeMessage(...) // <-  compilation error here
          } else {
            root ! makeMessage(...) // <-  compilation error here
          }
        }
      case OtherOp1(...) => ???
      case OtherOp2(...) => ???
    }
  }
}
```

Here the error the console displays :

```
MyFile.scala:161: type mismatch;
  found   : Unit
  required: MyActor.this.Receive
     (which expands to)  PartialFunction[Any,Unit]
             root ! makeMessage(...)
                  ^
 6 errors found
(assignment/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 108 s, completed Dec 19, 2013 9:07:46 PM
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is Assignment 5 from the [Principles of Reactive Programming course](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive). It should be marked as such. Also, the hard deadline expires on 22Dec. I don't believe it is in accordance with the Honor Code you agreed to for the course to post large code snippets of answers like that.

Comment: I only post the code snippet that is relevant to my question. I dont think it's against the honor code. As suggested, i will update the tag of question.

Comment: 1. I didn't mean the tag (which is blacklisted AFAIR), I meant to include the relevant info in the question. Otherwise yours could be interpreted by someone else as dishonest behavior. 2. Sure, posting small pieces is normally fine, but in **my opinion** this question and answer crosses the line into "not OK" territory.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: I'm not in this course and my answer is just an obvious type fix + minor refactoring without any secret knowledge.

Comment: @senia : sorry, I was imprecise. I didn't mean that I see your behavior as purposefully unethical (and neither do I do Dimitri's). I just meant that the end effect is, again in my opinion, "not OK" in the context of what's accepted on SO and Coursera, regardless of anyone's intentions. And it's mostly the question that is at fault of course, your answer is indeed mostly innocuous.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: question and answer are fixed. Is it "OK" now? (AFAIR you have enough reputation to edit any post without confirmation).

Comment: @senia : yep, looks good, thanks for the fix (I know, I was hoping for the OP to fix this to be honest :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Replace this line:

```
private def makeOperation(...): Receive = {
```

With this:

```
private def makeOperation(...): Unit = {
```

Result type of your expression `operation match { ... }` is `Unit`, since it's the result type of the last method (`!`) in every brunch.

#### Details

Method `makeOperation` is wrong named. What it really do is processing messages.

Actually you don't need this method at all - you could process messages in `normal` like this:

```
val normal: Receive = {
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, true)
    if otherInt < someInt => root ! makeMessage(...)
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, true)
    if otherInt > someInt => ...
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, true) => ...
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, false)
    if otherInt < someInt => ...
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, false)
    if otherInt > someInt => ...
  case Outer(MainOp(otherInt), someInt, false) => ...
  case Outer(OtherOp1(...), someInt, someBool) => ...
  case Outer(OtherOp2(...), someInt, someBool) => ...
}
```

You'd need a method with result type `Receive` only if you want to change actor's behavior for **next** message (and all messages after) like this:

```
context become createNewBehavior(params)
```

See these answers for examples:

[Initializing an actor before being able to handle some other messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591124/initializing-an-actor-before-being-able-to-handle-some-other-messages/20591331#20591331)

[How to properly use akka actors in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207780/how-to-properly-use-akka-actors-in-scala/17208523#17208523)

[Is it possible to do that in Scala (without mutating the internal state of a class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997573/is-it-possible-to-do-that-in-scala-without-mutating-the-internal-state-of-a-cla/16997958#16997958)